# Last record each group in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql

I has a table with schema:

```
create table last_message_by_group
(
    date        date,
    created_at  timestamp,
    message     text,
    group_id    bigint,
    primary key (date, created_at, message_id)
) 
  with clustering order by (created_at desc)
```

and data should be:

```
|     date    | created_at | message | group_id |
|  2021-05-11 |  7:23:54   | ddd     |    1     | 
|  2021-05-11 |  6:21:43   | ccc     |    1     | 
|  2021-05-11 |  5:35:16   | bbb     |    2     |
|  2021-05-11 |  4:38:23   | aaa     |    2     |
```

It will show messages order by created_at desc partition by date.

But the problem is it can not get last message each group likes:

```
|     date    | created_at | message | group_id |
|  2021-05-11 |  7:23:54   | ddd     |    1     | 
|  2021-05-11 |  5:35:16   | bbb     |    2     |
```

created_at is cluster key, so it cant be updated, so I delete and insert new row every new message by group_id, this way make low performance

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by making one change to your primary key definition.  I added `group_id` as the first clustering key:

```
PRIMARY KEY (date, group_id, created_at, message_id)
```

After inserting the same data, this works:

```
> SELECT date, group_id, max(created_at), message
  FROM last_message_by_group
  WHERE date='2021-05-11'
  GROUP BY date,group_id;

 date       | group_id | system.max(created_at)          | message
------------+----------+---------------------------------+---------
 2021-05-11 |        1 | 2021-05-11 12:23:54.000000+0000 |     ddd
 2021-05-11 |        2 | 2021-05-11 10:35:16.000000+0000 |     bbb

(2 rows)
```

There's more detail on using CQL's [GROUP BY](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/dml.html#grouping-results) clause in the official docs.

> there is one problem, because you changed clustering key, so message will be ordered by group_id first. Any idea for still order by created_at and 1 message each group?

From the document linked above:

> the `GROUP BY` option only accept as arguments primary key column names in the primary key order.

Unfortunately, if we were to adjust the primary key definition to put `created_at` *before* `group_id`, we would also have to group by `created_at`.  That would create a "group" for each unique `created_at`, which negates the idea behind `group_id`.

In this case, you may have to decide between having the grouped results in a particular order vs. having them grouped at all.  It might also be possible to group the results, but then re-order them appropriately on the application side.

Comment: Thank you, it seems the answer I'm looking for. I wonder we can make group by in materialize view?

Comment: @JackyMao Just tried it, and "no" it doesn't look like `GROUP BY` works in a materialized view.

Comment: there is one problem, because you changed clustering key, so message will be ordered by group_id first. Any idea for still order by created_at and 1 message each group?